# Drupal views sorting with two criteria

Tags: mysql, drupal-7, subquery, drupal-views

I want to alter my view query to change my query view.

So i want to add a query like:

```
<select From (select from where) order by) order by >
```

to just order my data twice.

Also is there any other way to do what I want even if not using the `hook_view_query_alter`?

I tried a lot of methods and modules (views_php, views_raw_sql, view_field_View) and 
also tried stored procedures but  did not know how to call it in the Drupal view

Any idea or hint please?

Comment: You should add a little more context to your question. Is your problem that you cannot get the right query to work or is it a Drupal problem?

Comment: sorry for that.my first problem is that i was trying to sort my view due 2 dates(first with the post date)then with a field of mine (start date) so i get the data sorted desc by the post date then sort it again asc with the start date field.so i tried to change the query to be nested select statement.if you can tell me how to do that in that way or any other way to do the same thing ,this will be kind of you. thanks for your kind reply .

Comment: Can you post what your query looks like at the moment? What DBMS are you using? If you're using subqueries in MySQL, the syntax is `SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE column1 = (SELECT column1 FROM t2);`.

Comment: SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT t1.column1  , t2.column2
  t1.column3, 
t1.column4,t1.column6
FROM t1, t2s
WHERE ((t1.status = '1') AND (t1.type IN ('events')) AND t2.column3 = 'events' 
AND column1 .id = column2.nid)
ORDER BY t1.column1 DESC LIMIT 3)
 AS t 
ORDER BY t2.column2 ASC

Comment: and i don't know how to alter the view query to change view query with my query . thanks again

Comment: any one can tell me how to do that even in another way !!??

Comment: ok thanks .that is my query (i test it in sql yog and seems to work).SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT node.nid AS nid, FROM_UNIXTIME(node.created)
 AS node_created,  field_data_field_date_events.field_date_events_value AS from_date
FROM node, field_data_field_date_events
WHERE ((node.status = '1') AND (node.type IN ('events')) AND field_data_field_date_events.bundle = 'events' 
AND field_data_field_date_events.entity_id = node.nid)
ORDER BY node_created DESC LIMIT 3)
 AS t 
ORDER BY from_date ASC

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a nested `SELECT` clause to add another sort criteria to the query. The following syntax will do what you want:

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
ORDER BY date1, date2
```

This will sort the results by date1 and then by date2.

In Views, simply add another sort criteria to the View you're editing, it's that simple.

Comment: thanks for your reply ,i have already add the second sort criteria but this results in first level sorting based on date1 and if two events with the same date1 exist  those two records only will perform a second level sorting which is based on date2 field .and this is not what i a want to do.i want to sort to date 1 and all data is sorted to date1 (which is the post date/ descending ) and then select from the sorted data the events with date2(which is an event start date) ascending.

Comment: OK, I think I get what you want now. The `LIMIT` clause in the nested select means that you need to obtain the 3 latest events (by date1) and then sort them by date2. Is that correct?

Comment: yes it is ,and if there is any other way(drupal way) even if not using hook_view_query_alter i will appreciate that.my project is depending on that sort and i am still a junior .thanks again.

Comment: If you can rewrite the query so that the subquery is in the WHERE statement, things may be a bit easier. You could then do $query->add_where() in hook_views_query_alter() to add the extra WHERE condition that utilizes the subquery.